# How to add same component inside components

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I tried to do task below, but i am stuck, How can I structure my components in a way that, it will be possible for nesting same component inside component.
[image]
[image: Components]

**App.js file**

```
render () {
return (
  <main className="wrapper">
    <div className="row">
      <Container addBox = { this.addBox } 
                 boxes = {this.state.containers} 
                 changeColor={this.changeColor}
                 addContainer = {this.addContainer}
                 containers={this.state.containers}/>
    </div>
  </main>
);
```

}

Comment: You should do it in the `Container` component. Like you add Container in app.js, create `Box` component and add it to Container.js, set the props as you did in this one

Comment: @OnerT. I did it in a same way as you said, but how should i define state? I tried to add containers state in app.js, but stuck because my boxes should be inside containers state even other containers may be inside container

Comment: check my answer. If you want to map multiple Boxes for example, I will add solution for that also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you add Container in app.js, create Box component and add it to Container.js, set the props as you did in this one, something like this:

```
import Container from "./Container.js"

state={ data1 : "something" }

render () {
return (
  <main className="wrapper">
    <div className="row">
      <Container addBox = { this.addBox } 
                 propsAgain={this.state.data1}
                 changeColor={this.changeColor}
                 addContainer = {this.addContainer}
                 containers={this.state.containers}/>
    </div>
  </main>
);
```

Container.js:

```
import Box from "./Box.js"



render () {
const{propsAgain}=this.props // we pass it upper again
return (

    <div className="row">
      <Box props1 = {propsAgain}  
    </div>

);
```

Box.js:

```
render () {
const {props1, props2} = this.props // these are props to pass to parent component
return (

    <div>{props1}</div> 

);
```

If you want to pass the grandchildren components' data to the upper component, you can pass the props to one step up, define props again and pass it to one step up again

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did it in exactly same way, Now I am confused how state should be, and how to put, other container inside container and boxes inside newly created container, could you please try to look to the picture where task is described and help me to implement it, thank you again